# Kali Linux not Updating

Tags: linux, debian, security, kali-linux, apt

I am trying to update my kali linux version, but whenever I try to execute `sudo apt update` command, it gives me the following output:

```
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]                                                                                           
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                      
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zeehio/libxp/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                                               
Hit:5 https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable InRelease                                                                   
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu groovy Release                                                              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zeehio/libxp/ubuntu groovy Release                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:6 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease                 
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/zeehio/libxp/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have tried to update my `/etc/apt/resources.list` file, but still the same problem, I do not even know what are these ubuntu messages in the output. Now the `resources.list` file is as follows:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Comment: You've broken your Kali distribution. Please read https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/ in particular the section "Non-Kali Repositories", which ends with "_adding other operating system’s repositories into Kali (such as trying to put Ubuntu on Kali), will break your installation. This is the single most common reason why Kali Linux systems break_"

Comment: You are right, I found some package files stored in `/etc/apt/resources.d` file that caused the error

Comment: /etc/sources.d and sources.list. Not /etc/resources.d or resources.list

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the directory containing the external packages that broke Kali
by using the command `cd /etc/apt/resources.d`.

Type `ls` to list the packages in the directory.

Remove the packages one after the other by using
`sudo rm "package name"`.

Comment: The command `cd` cannot be used with `sudo` as `cd` is not a program, `sudo` elevates only programs. You do not need to manually remove one by one, JUST do `sudo rm -f *`. I have edited your answer to fix the errors, and its under queue